# Error in if (output1 != arg) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, data-cleaning

I was trying to gsub some dirty data like these "cds 9"; "cTT-9";"lee" in the data frame by building a function; and then lapply it to the dataframe

I have tested for several input like "cds 9"; "cTT-9";"lee"
and they all gave me the expected results as "CDS9";"CTT9";"LEE"

```
`data_clean <- function(arg) { 
   outcome<-arg
   output1<-gsub(pattern=" ",replacement="",arg)
   if (output1!=arg){outcome<-output1}
   output2<-gsub(pattern="-",replacement="",arg)
   if (output2!=arg){outcome<-output2}
   toupper(outcome)
 }

 df<-lapply(df, data_clean)`
```

However,when i lapply the function to my data frame, it printed out this:

"Error in if (output1 != arg) { : argument is of length zero"

P.S. the data frame looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCM4X.png)

Comment: Can you please share your input data frame? It will be easier to help you if your question is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3277821).

Comment: Yeah, sure,thank you

Comment: Are there any NULLs / NAs in the data set? Is the data set image a complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `gsub` and `toupper` to every column with `lapply`, then recombine the results using `do.call` and `cbind`:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("A b", "a-B", "Ab"),
  B = c("c D", "c-D", "cD")
)

do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(x) toupper(gsub("\\s|-", "", x))))
#>      A    B   
#> [1,] "AB" "CD"
#> [2,] "AB" "CD"
#> [3,] "AB" "CD"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

`gsub` uses the regular expression `\\s|-` to replace either a space (`\\s`) or a dash (`-`) with `""`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this question! It works on my data now, but still cannot figure out why my function does not work when lapply to my dataframe

Comment: What do you mean 'not work when lapply to my dataframe'?  In other words, what is the object returned by your code and what do you expect?  Not that `lapply` will always return a `list`, and not a `data.frame`.